# how can i parse this json in jquery 1.2.6

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

```
{
    letter: [{
        "description": "aaaa",
        "date": "19.02.2012 21:34:26",
        "lid": "6",
        "companyname": "ml",
        "personname": "jenny konste",
        "email": "jenk@ml.com",
        "fax": "123123",
        "phone": "345345",
        "industryname": "finance",
        "teamname": "b1",
        "sender": "vivien jacobien",
        "statusname": "interested"},
    {
        "description": "asdasdadsadsa",
        "date": "19.02.2012 21:37:03",
        "lid": "9",
        "companyname": "ford",
        "personname": "charles",
        "email": "charlesb@ford.com",
        "fax": "11111",
        "phone": "777777",
        "industryname": "automotive",
        "teamname": "b3",
        "sender": "clementine",
        "statusname": "rejected"}]
}
```

Comment: this is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since parseJSON was introduced in jQuery 1.4.1 you could use [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) jquery - json library or you could use `JSON.parse()`

§EDIT you need to stringify the object before converting it to JSON. This works

```
var json = {
    letter: [{
        "description": "aaaa",
        "date": "19.02.2012 21:34:26",
        "lid": "6",
        "companyname": "ml",
        "personname": "jenny konste",
        "email": "jenk@ml.com",
        "fax": "123123",
        "phone": "345345",
        "industryname": "finance",
        "teamname": "b1",
        "sender": "vivien jacobien",
        "statusname": "interested"},
    {
        "description": "asdasdadsadsa",
        "date": "19.02.2012 21:37:03",
        "lid": "9",
        "companyname": "ford",
        "personname": "charles",
        "email": "charlesb@ford.com",
        "fax": "11111",
        "phone": "777777",
        "industryname": "automotive",
        "teamname": "b3",
        "sender": "clementine",
        "statusname": "rejected"}]
}

var parsed = $.secureEvalJSON(JSON.stringify(json));
  alert(parsed.letter[1].description);
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5ezyx/

Comment: why my code says its undefined? success: function (msg) {
                    var name = $.evalJSON(msg).companyname;
                    alert(name);

Comment: @tfeseas i think that it uses `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.parse()` returns an error when parsing that json

Comment: how can i overcome the situation? i am able to show json data by alert but not able to parse it on the next line

Comment: @tfeseas i updated my answer, you need to convert the object to a string before converting it to JSON

Comment: real returned json doesnt have {letter:   and } at the end.

Comment: it works on fiddle not on my computer.                              dataType: "application/json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var parsed = $.secureEvalJSON(JSON.stringify(msg));
                    alert(parsed[0].description);
    

                }

Comment: could it be because i use it not onload but on success of ajax post?

Comment: @tfeseas no it shouldn't matter

Comment: then why doesn't it work on my computer?i mean when i copy it to fiddler it works but when i run it locally it doesnt show anything

Answer (score 0):

@tfeseas 
At the beginning of the JSON string, i see `letter` which is not in double quotes. That makes it invalid JSON. Maybe that's why you are having trouble parsing the string into an object?

Comment: i forgot to change code here.sorry there is no letter in the actual json returned.i try my code in fiddler and it works but when i try it locally it doesnt.all the code is in an .ascx file which is a widget that is loaded dynamically to my homepage adn that page loads jquery 1.2.6.js.everything works except for parsing part.

Answer (score 0):

Additional from me. Maybe someone searching for this:
Use $.evalJSON to create objectData from string.